# Image Diffrence Using openCv

Tags: opencv

Im trying to detect the difference between two images :

image 1 :
[image]

image 2 :
[image]

The result I want is to have an image that doesn't contain the shared elements.

The problem that I'm facing is that when i do an image.diff, I get some lines around the edges of the shared elements.
and i don't want those to be detected.

Image 3 : is what I'm getting now those lines that have x in red shouldn't be there.

Is there anyway to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had is that I generated the second image from the first image using the `Erode` method and that ate away some pixles,
So instead I used `MorphologyEx` method.

```
Mat layersToRemove = new Mat();
Mat element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Rect, new Size(5, 5)); 
Cv2.MorphologyEx(whiteMask, layersToRemove, MorphTypes.Open, element);
```

The I applied a simple `Substract`

```
Mat output = new Mat();
Cv2.Subtract(image1, layersToRemove, output);
res.SaveImage("C:/output.png");
```